# AngularJS filter to display something else if a variable is undefined

Tags: angularjs, filter, undefined

In my AngularJS app, I created a recursive template.

For illustration, it works something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in stuff">
     <div ng-include="'myTemplate.html'" onload="item = item"></div>
</div>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
         <h1> {{levelsDeep | "root"}} </h1>
         <h2> {{item.content}} </h2>
         <div ng-include="'myTemplate.html'" onload="item in item.innerItem; levelsDeep = levelsDeep+'->'"></div>
</script>
```

In this recursive template, I want the top level line to read "root" and the inner levels to read '->->->' etc, depending on how deeply nested they are.

Is there a filter to check if `levelsDeep` has not yet been defined (like in the first step) and then print "`root`" if this is so?

Comment: can you try creating a plunker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the javascript OR (`||`) operator

`{{levelsDeep||"root"}}`